# Creating a thread is not working

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a thread into a project I am working on and I am not sure where i am going wrong.
    package Project;

```
public class Launch{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Threads thread = new Threads();
    thread.start();
    }
}

class Threads implements Runnable{
static FruitSpawn spawn = new FruitSpawn();
    public void run(){
        spawn.spawnFruit();
    }
}
```

The program is asking me to create a method called start() in Threads instead of stating the thread. Where am i going wrong in creating the thread? I am working in Java thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Threads` is just implementing `Runnable` not extending `Thread` so you can't call `start()` on it.

Do:

```
Thread  t =new Thread(new Threads());
t.start();
```

Comment: Thanks i though you used extends Runnable but my ide gave me an error and changed it to implements Runnable

Answer (score 1):

You create a `Thread`, giving it your `Runnable` to run and then start it.

```
class Threads implements Runnable {

    static FruitSpawn spawn = new FruitSpawn();

    public void run() {
        spawn.spawnFruit();
    }
}

public void test() {
    Threads spawner = new Threads();
    Thread t = new Thread(spawner);
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like:

```
 Threads thread = new Threads(this);
   thread.start();
```

`thread.start()` creates a new thread and have its own execution scenario. `thread.start()` calls the run method asyc.when come to running state.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your  `Runnable` to Thread class while initialization.

```
public class Launch{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable runabl = new Threads(); 
    Threads thread = new Threads(runabl);
    thread.start();
    }
}

class Threads implements Runnable{
static FruitSpawn spawn = new FruitSpawn();
    public void run(){
        spawn.spawnFruit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Threads is implementing Runnable interface, and not extending Thread class.  So, either you should 
(a) Let Threads class implement Runnable and use 
new Thread(new Threads()).start();

or

(b) Enhance Threads class to extend Thread class and not implement Runnable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Majorly speaking `Thread Class has 4-flavour`(other too but rarely used) of `Constructor` likewise,

```
 1. Thread(),
 2. Thread(String threadName),
 3. Thread(Runnable target),
 4. Thread(Runnable target, String threadName).
```

Now you have `Threads class which implements Runnable Interface.`

So Object of `Threads class called Runnable type Object`.

Now you have to pass that Threads class Object into `3rd flavor of Thread Class constructor.`

so do following changes in your code and enjoy !!

```
public class Launch{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Threads runnableObject= new Threads();
    Thread t = new Thread(runnableObject); // among of above listed 3rd flavor of Thread class constructor.
    t.start(); // start thread which will call run() of Threads Class.
    }
```

}